# Restfull service : status code return

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, restful-architecture

I am writing restfull ws and confused about what status code I should return.
Does it depends on business logic .

1) client call my ws and ws is successfully called. From business logic perspective it is a success case. So in this case I am sending 200 OK with Successful msg.

2) client call my ws and ws is successfully called. From business logic perspective it is a failed case ie emp id not present. So in this case I am sending 200 OK with emp id not present msg. So here should I send 200 OK or any other status code.

3) If some exception occurred in my business logic then I am sending 200 OK with technical failure msg. Is this correct

What is the standards.

Comment: Try and follow [this](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) when possible

Comment: Take a look at [HTTP status codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes). For example you should use `400 Bad Request` if the client sent an invalid request.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the standard HTTP status codes. 
To answer your questions:

1. Here HTTP OK (200) is the correct response
2. You should return a HTTP NOT FOUND (404) with (optionally/depending on your business logic) a useful message what was not found.
3. Here you should return HTTP INTERNAL SERVER ERROR (500), optionally (if the clients needs to know) with a message what has gone wrong

[HTTP Status Codes](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)